# javascript length of each file in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of files here and I want to check the length of each file. 
If length is zero then return false.

```
function check()
{
    var files = ["#File1","#File2","#File3"];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                if ($("#").find(files[i].val().length == 0)) {
                    return false
            }
    }
}
```

I am getting an exception "is not a valid function" here, can someone tell what is wrong in this statement which checks that each array element has some value.

```
if ($("#").find(files[i].val().length == 0))
```

Comment: what are you expecting with `$("#")` ?, also I guess `String` has no method `val`

Comment: Are these elements `<input type="file">` ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ($("#").find(files[i].val().length == 0)) {
```

By

```
if ($(files[i]).val().length == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (possibly incorrectly, since it's somewhat unclear) that the elements are actually `<input type="file">` inputs and that it's the size of the selected files you want rather than the filenames, you can examine the `files` property of each element and get the `size` property of each element of that array:

```js
$('#File1').on('change', function() {
  alert(this.files[0].size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="File1">
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to check, if alle the files are given within input fields? Your check could look like this:

`if ($(files[i]).val().length == 0)`

I prepared **a simple pen** to show how the function check() could work on a button:
http://codepen.io/rias/pen/emjxJv

Also you could iterate through all of the input fields, if you give them a common class like `.file-input` and use jQuery to iterate over them:

```
function check () {
  $('.file-input).each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return true; //return true, if everything is okay!
}
```